# MYSQL - How to check if a column has value or is it null and another column has value like 10

Tags: mysql, sql, database, where-clause

Lets say i have a table with 3 columns id, user and status.
I need to find rows which have status as 1 or null and user = 'someName'

I am lookin for a condition like this:
if (user == 'name' && status == 1 || status == null)

How do i do this in mysql

Comment: [`WHERE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/where-optimization.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just:

```
WHERE user = 'someName' AND (status = 1 OR status IS NULL)
```

This can be simplified as the shorter (but possibly less efficient)

```
WHERE user = 'someName' AND IFNULL(status, 1) = 1
```

---

Note that this does not exactly the same thing as your pseudo-code:

```
user == 'name' && status == 1 || status == null
```

Is equivalent to:

```
( user == 'name' && status == 1 ) || status == null
```

Which would translate as:

```
WHERE (user = 'someName' AND status = 1) OR status IS NULL
```

My understanding of your question, however, is that you *meant* the first above conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You may try below -

```
SELECT * FROM TAB
WHERE user = 'Some Name'
AND (status = 1 OR status IS NULL)
```

Comment: `user == 'name' && status == 1 || status == null` is different than `user = 'name' AND (status = 1 OR status IS NULL)`. `AND` has a higher predecence over `OR`